# caprover laravel nginx 502 issue

Tags: php, laravel, docker, caprover

I'm using CapRover in my VDS (virtual dedicated server) and I want to deploy my Laravel application. When I run the CapRover deploy command there is no problem with deployment. Also, I am deploying with .env and vendor file , but when I go to the URL, CapRover return NGINX 502 Error.

here my Dockerfile:

```
FROM joseluisq/php-fpm:8.2
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80
```